# How can I fix the segmentation error in this nested loop?

Tags: c, iteration

I have a maze guiding program, but it has been stuck in one line. It is the mouse locator, that searches through array of pointers to locate 'M' or the mouse in the maze. The code constantly gives out segmentation errors.

```
void iterative_search(char **maze, int rows, int cols, char *directions) {
    int x = -1, y = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            if (maze[i][j] == 'M') { //<- segmentation fault happens here.
                break;
            }
        }
        if (maze[x][y] == 'M') {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if (x == rows && y == cols) {
        printf("Error: Jerry not found in the maze.\n");
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; directions[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        int new_x = x;
        int new_y = y;
        switch (directions[i]) {
        case 'N':
            new_x--;
            break;
        case 'E':
            new_y++;
            break;
        case 'S':
            new_x++;
            break;
        case 'W':
            new_y--;
            break;
        default:
            continue;
        }
    
        if (new_x >= 0 && new_y >= 0 && new_x < rows && new_y < cols &&
            (maze[new_x][new_y] == ' ' || maze[new_x][new_y] == 'C')) {
            if (maze[x][y] != 'M') {
                maze[x][y] = '.';
            }
            x = new_x;
            y = new_y;
            if (maze[x][y] == 'C') {
                printf("Jerry found the cheese at (%d, %d)!\n", x, y);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the rest of the code that has allocation and the calling of the function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void iterative_search(char **maze, int rows, int cols, char *directions);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Error: Please provide two input files via command line arguments.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *maze_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE *directions_file = fopen(argv[2], "r");

    if (!maze_file || !directions_file) {
        printf("Error: Could not open input files.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int rows, cols;
    // Read in maze from maze_file and store in 2D array
    fscanf(maze_file, "%d %d", &rows, &cols);
    fgetc(maze_file); // consume the newline character after reading rows and cols

    char **maze = malloc(rows * sizeof(char *));
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        maze[i] = malloc((cols + 1) * sizeof(char));
        fgets(maze[i], cols + 1, maze_file);
    }
    fclose(maze_file);


    char *directions = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    while ((read = getline(&directions, &len, directions_file)) != -1) {
        iterative_search(maze, rows, cols, directions);
    }
    fclose(directions_file);


    // Write iterative search output to file
    FILE *iterative_output = fopen("iterative_output.out", "w");
    if (iterative_output) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            fprintf(iterative_output, "%s", maze[i]);
        }
        fclose(iterative_output);
    } else {
        printf("Error: Could not create iterative_output.out file.\n");
    }

    
    // Free dynamically allocated memory and close files
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        free(maze[i]);
    }
    free(maze);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char **M` declares an array of pointers, which is not the same as a 2D array.

Comment: Show us the code that allocates the maze and calls this function.

Comment: I have added to the question and fixed the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies here:

```
    int x = -1, y = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            if (maze[i][j] == 'M') { //<- segmentation fault happens here.
                break;
            }
        }
        if (maze[x][y] == 'M') {
            break;
        }
    }
```

You have these variables `x` and `y` which are used extensively in this function. However, they are never actually set to anything useful. Instead you have these loop-local variables `i` and `j`.

You probably mean to do:

```
    for (y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
```

So that `x` and `y` get set to your target coordinates.

The access of `maze[-1][-1]` that you do leads to undefined behaviour and is the probable cause of your segmentation fault.

You've not provided enough information for me to test this fix, so there may be other problems.